# How do I use keras to load my own customized dataset for convolution neural network

Tags: python, keras

Below is sample code for imdb dataset.I am a beginner and following a tutorial, I am trying to load my own dataset in keras.How would I modify the code.I would be very grateful

```
import keras
#Using keras to load the dataset with the top_words
max_features = 10000 #max number of words to include, words are ranked by how often they occur (in training set)
max_review_length = 1600

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(nb_words=max_features)
print 'loaded dataset...'
#Pad the sequence to the same length
X_train = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=max_review_length)
X_test = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=max_review_length)

index_dict = keras.datasets.imdb.get_word_index()
```

Comment: I think the 6th line should be `keras.datasets.imdb.load_data` and you also need to define where `sequence` comes from. As for loading the data it completely depends on the dataset you're wokring with. If it's just numeric data in a CSV format, you can load with `numpy.loadtxt` to get it in a numpy array similarly to the iris dataset in your example.

Comment: I have a text classification dataset in csv format,with the label id in first column and the text in the next column

Comment: Ok, in that case I'd load the CSV file either with Pandas (`pd.read_csv('csv_file.csv')`) or with the `csv` module. You can use Scikit-learn's CountVectorizer to represent the text in a similar way to the IMDB dataset (`from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer`) in order to build the feature vectors and you'll then need to split into train and test sets.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution with Pandas and CountVectorizer. You'll then need to pad the data and split into test and train as above.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

data = {
    'label': [0, 1, 0, 1],
    'text': ['first bit of text', 'second bit of text', 'third text', 'text number four']
}
data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

# Form vocab dictionary
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit_transform(data['text'].tolist())
vocab_text = vectorizer.vocabulary_

# Convert text
def convert_text(text):
    text_list = text.split(' ')
    return [vocab_text[t]+1 for t in text_list]

data['text'] = data['text'].apply(convert_text)

# Get X and y matrices
y = np.array(data['label'])
X = np.array(data['text'])
```

Comment: would you please elaborate how to do it for as I have my labels in column[0] and texts in column[1] in csv format?`.I know it sounds weired but I am really a newbie to this field

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv(<path_to_csv_file>)` to load the csv and
`df.columns = ['label', 'text']`  to set the column names.

You can use `df.head(n=10)` to print the first 10 rows of the dataframe, which should be in the same format as the one I've defined.

Comment: yeah got it.Thanks